# How do I add a shortcut to a website to the Windows 8 start screen?

Tags: windows-8, start-screen

How can I add a shortcut to a specific website to the Windows 8 Start screen? Is this possible at all?

Comment: See this, have not tried it...http://www.mmo-champion.com/threads/977781-Windows-8-Adding-Shortcuts-to-Metro-UI

Comment: what an effort is required to add a website to the tiles. (if it really works, haven't tried it yet). Will MS fix this?

Comment: Remember its Beta software right now.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Only in the Metro version of IE 10 can you 'Pin to Start'.

In IE, Programs Tab, check there is NO tick next to Open Internet Explorer tiles on the desktop.  That was just to ensure that the Metro version of IE 10 is active.

Once IE 10 launches, navigate to the site you are interested in.  Right-click (or swipe from the top or bottom edge) and find the "push pin" icon.

Click on the pin icon, then 'Pin to Start' in the menu. Adjust the title if required and press "Pin to Start". Return to the start screen and search the right of the Metro UI for your shortcut tile.

Comment: Sorry for that sloppiness, now corrected.  Glad you got the job done.

Comment: It's now also possible in the desktop version of IE10 to Pin to start

Comment: @GuyThomas - Please update this answer with the most current information since its the accepted answer.

Comment: @Ramhound Not quite sure what to add.  But will investigate.

Comment: @GuyThomas - We have somebody that claims its possible to pin using the desktop IE10.  Just confirm this to be true or false.  If its false flag the comment.

Comment: To me; Zao's original question was specifically about the Start Screen (Metro UI).  Zao’s subsequent comment switches the emphasis to the Windows 8 DESKTOP.  I can confirm that IE 10, when launched from the desktop behaves the same as IE 9 does in Windows 7, namely you can right click a website in the browser and then ‘Drag to taskbar to pin site’.  However, this does NOT add a shortcut back at the Start Screen.

Comment: It is possible in IE 10 Desktop Mode to pin a site to the start screen: click the cog and then click Add site to Start Screen

Answer (score 4):

It's possible in Google Chrome too:

- open the page with Chrome
- go to Tools → Create application shortcut

This should create the shortcut on your desktop. Then go to your desktop and pin it to the Start menu.

Comment: this will open the website in app mode. If you'd prefer to open the website in a new tab in an existing chrome window, edit the shortcut and remove `--app=` in front of the URL.

Answer (score 0):

Refer the [official MSDN help](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ie/gg618532%28v=vs.85%29.aspx).

> **How to Pin a Website**
>
> To pin a site with Internet Explorer 9, drag the tab from the browser to the taskbar. Alternatively, you can drag the site icon from the address bar or from the New Tab page and drop it on the taskbar to pin the site.
>
> **Note**  Windows 8: In Internet Explorer 10, site pinning on the desktop works the same as Internet Explorer 9. In the new Windows UI experience, however, you pin a site by pressing the Pin to Start button.