# How to pin a website to the Windows 8 Start screen with Internet Explorer as default browser?

Tags: windows-8, internet-explorer, start-screen

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How do I add a shortcut to a website to the windows 8 start menu?](https://superuser.com/questions/416575/how-do-i-add-a-shortcut-to-a-website-to-the-windows-8-start-menu)

I'm not sure if I like the whole idea of Start screen yet, but I would find it more useful with certain web based sites as a tiles in the group.

This question is similar to my other one at: [How to pin a website to the Windows 8 Start screen without Internet Explorer as default browser?](https://superuser.com/questions/499486/how-to-pin-a-website-to-the-windows-8-start-screen-without-internet-explorer-as) but this is meant to cover only those using IE as their default!

Comment: Geez enough with the "possible dupe" everything is a dupe since they are all questions :)

Comment: Well when it's a possible duplicate I mark them as such. It's the way things go around here. :)

Comment: True, but its a specific question that is a "noted" twist on another question; I still believe its relevant an helpful being that I actually had this issue after I installed Win8.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1. Right-click on your desktop and select "New" > "Shortcut", to create a new shortcut.
2. Create a shortcut to Internet Explorer with the website that you want as an argument:

   "C:\Program Files (x86)\Internet Explorer\iexplore.exe" www.google.com

   Name it as you may want, "Google.com" on my example.
3. Right-click on the shortcut you had just created.
4. Click on "Pin to Start".

Thats all, now you have a tile that opens Internet Explorer with a personalized page.