# SOLVED - Open Internet Explorer Desktop version from Start?

Tags: windows-8, internet-explorer, taskbar, modern-ui

Is it possible to pin IE tiles that when you tap it, it open IE in desktop mode?
I imagine it will be possible to make a shortcut with `iexplorer.exe /somecommand` or something like that and then pin it to Start, but I don't know the command, there must be some sort of flag command since IE pinned in taskbar is always open in desktop and IE pinned in Start Screen always open as Modern IE.

The end result I want is to have 2 tiles of IE on Start, one for desktop and the other for Modern version. Yes, IE is the default browser.

**UPDATE**:
Found a workaround. Since the Modern IE pinned in Start is IE 64 bit, I can pin the IE 32 bit as desktop shortcut.

Since the question is marked as duplicate, I can't make an answer.

Comment: So your basically asking how to start the Modern UI IE from the desktop?

Comment: Also see [Doigo's answer](http://superuser.com/a/500144/23133) on this question: [How to pin a website to the Windows 8 Start screen with Internet Explorer as default browser?](http://superuser.com/questions/500134/how-to-pin-a-website-to-the-windows-8-start-screen-with-internet-explorer-as-def)

Comment: @Ramhound no, it's the other way around, to open desktop IE from the start screen.

Comment: @Nur - The solution is the same.  You just pin the shortcut to the desktop application on the start screen.

Comment: @Ramhound It's not the same, it is similar but still I can't pin the shortcut if I don't specify the address, since IE already pinned. Nonetheless that'll do my client can't tell the difference anyway until he change the homepage. Thanks I guess.