# Create a Short cut to a URL on the start menu windows 8

Tags: windows, modern-ui, desktop-customization, windows-8

how do I create a tile on my windows 8 start menu that will open a browser and go to a specific URL..

any ideas?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do I add a shortcut to a website to the Windows 8 start screen?](http://superuser.com/questions/416575/how-do-i-add-a-shortcut-to-a-website-to-the-windows-8-start-screen), [How to pin a website to the Windows 8 Start screen without Internet Explorer as default browser?](http://superuser.com/questions/499486/how-to-pin-a-website-to-the-windows-8-start-screen-without-internet-explorer-as)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Go to the URL in IE:

Desktop version:

- Open Tools (Alt + T)
- Click (or tap) 'Add Site to Apps'
- Go to Start Screen, open All Apps, right click (or hold) the new short cut, click Pin To Start

'Modern' version:

- Right click on an empty place (or swipe down)
- Click Pin Site
- Confirm by clicking Pin to Start